# Search query MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a database as follows
The first column is the name.
The second column bears the number of the son in the family.
The third column is the family Code.

-Explanatory information:
-The first column in the database. Contains the name of the father and children and they are not arranged
-The second column in the database. It contains the number of fathers and children in the database where the parents take nothing and the children take numbers.
-The third column in the database. It contains a code that is specific to each family and does not subscribe to any other family.

What is required when searching in query as follows:

The query is made for a specific name, where the search is for displaying all fields containing the same name if it is for a father or children.
Provided that the final form of the offer is to collect parents only and arrange them in ascending order.

- The data in the images is for illustration and the actual column names of the query

[image]

If you search for a name, let it be Ali, the result will be as follows  2  image:

[image]
2- The final result With the order of the parents in ascending name order.

[image]

MY TRY NOT WORK

```
SELECT PARENT_NAME, PARENT_NUMBER,PARENT_CODE
FROM PARENT_TB
HAVING (((PARENT_NUMBER) Is Null));
```

Comment: "not work" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Use WHERE instead of HAVING. Data makes no sense. Query uses field PARENT_NAME yet it is not in table. Show sample raw data and desired output as text tables, not images.

Comment: hi june7 . "not work" = Nothing appears, no result

Comment: `HAVING` is inappropriate the way you're using it. Replace it with `WHERE`. After that, find a good SQL tutorial or book to learn the basics.

Comment: I simply do not understand the question, please post all the columns & tables involved and the desired query output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a subquery:

```sql
SELECT 
    IIF(PARENT_NUMBER Is Null, 
        PARENT_NAME, 
        (Select T.PARENT_NAME 
        From PARENT_TB As T 
        Where T.PARENT_CODE = PARENT_TB.PARENT_CODE And T.PARENT_NUMBER Is Null)) As ParentName,
    PARENT_CODE
FROM 
    PARENT_TB
WHERE 
    PARENT_NUMBER = "Ali"
```